# Flatbuffers didn't generate a Get* method, but did generate *Builder (in c++)?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I recently started experimenting with flatbuffers and am facing a very strange problem. I am able to translate the flatb schema to c++ and compile my c++ code (which includes the generated c++) without errors. I am even able to encode a object using flatbuffers `MyEventBuilder(...)`. However, there isn't a corresponding `GetMyEvent(...)` method!

I grepped for `GetMyEvent` in the .h file generated by flatc and nothing of relevance shows up. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, this is too big of an issue for it to just be a bug. However, I've followed the docs pretty closely. I also posted this issue in the flatbuffers google group, no response yet.

Has anyone else seen this? Any ideas what could cause this (I'm hoping and assuming this is just a silly error on my end and not an issue with flatbuffers)?

TLDR: flatb generate a method to encode my c++ object to a byte array, but not a method to convert a byte array back to a c++ object!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have `root_type` defined in your Flatbuffer definition? I've discovered, that Get methon is only generated for table with this defined.